# Log cat displays RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, code seems ok at first glance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm not sure why LogCat is giving me this message:

RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Trawling through docs, SO and various tutorials I can't find my mistake, can someone point me in the right direction?

Code from onCreate()

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new PostAdapter(this, postList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

App compiles fine but the view is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That log message simply means you are setting the layout manager before providing the data it needs to layout, i.e. PostAdapter. If you look at the source code of RecyclerView in the method dispatchLayout(), it returns if there isn't an adapter this skipping the rendering. This is fine to do and won't cause a crash but it also will not draw anything until something tells the RecyclerView to relayout and draw its Views. I'd recommend adding the layout manager after calling setAdapter().

Comment: Thanks. So the message doesn't necessarily explain my blank screen then?

Comment: Try moving the setAdapter call before setLayoutManager().

Comment: @FullerPrime I've modified my answer.